# Standard Java EE Directory Structure Vs. Intellij Directory Structure

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, directory-structure

I'm beginner in Java EE and I read in resources that **Standard** directory structure of Java EE is this way :

[image: Standard Java EE Directory Structure]

but when I create a new project in **intellij idea**, directory structure of that is this way :

[image: Intellij Idea Directory Structure]

Now I'm Confused because of some reasons.

1. in Standard, WEB-INF is in same level with src but in Intellij type WEB-INF is in "web" directory.
2. in Intellij type , WEB-INF does not have "classes" and "lib" directory. instead of that, there is a "lib" directory in same level with src and "web"

can anyone please explain it for me ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both are correct.

The Java EE standard applies to the *packaged* web application.

IntelliJ uses a structure that applies to the source code.  I would recommend using the [Maven standard](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).

IntelliJ follows that standard when you create a web artifact.  It does not have a /lib folder because you should be managing your dependencies using Maven.  It does not have a /classes folder because that should be generated each time in your /target folder.

You need to tell IntelliJ how to create the web config as an artifact.

None of the generated assets should be committed into your source code management system (e.g. Git).

Comment: in Intellij type, when I put my jsp and html file in "web", then in my servlet which is in src, I can't address and find jsp and html files as parameter in getRequestDispatcher().

Comment: You have to create an artifact and move those files to the correct spots according to the Java EE standard.